# VUE same component instance at difference route

Tags: vue.js, components

I am design an Vuejs app which page render based on route.

e.g. for

route = /, Component = Main.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <toolbar :user="user"></toolbar>
    <app-content></app-content> 
  </div>
</template>
```

route = /:user, Component = User.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <toolbar :user="user"></toolbar>    
    <userHeader></userHeader>
    <app-content></app-content> 
  </div>
</template>
```

When the page is show, the toolbar component will fetch data from server, the problem is, when the page go from / to /user, the data fetching data X 2 because that are 2 toolbar components in the app itself.

How should resolve this issue ? is that any way to reuse share component instances like toolbar ?

or should i put the design in one whole component instead ? ( use v-if to show hide the additional component)

Comment: Can you share the template where you wrote `<router-view/>`?

Comment: I put in index.html. `<div id="app">
  <router-view></router-view>
 </div>`

Comment: You can put the <router-view/> in `App.vue` maybe, then share `<toolbar .../>` for both of your routers

Comment: I think the problem is still <toolbar> when using `import toolbar...` it will become a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be having `<toolbar />` outside of `<router-view></router-view>`.

So your code should look like:

```
<div id="app">
    <toolbar user="user" />
    <router-view />
</div>
```

With this `<toolbar />` won't change even if you change your routes, and will result in data fetching for a single time only.

Comment: yup, I now using nested route, some how they are not only toolbar will reuse, example, my content (which should only singleton) will use across difference nested route, and look like i got no way to SET the singleton content to the component.